# sudoers command with AND without arguments

Tags: sudo

How can I define a command both with and without arguments in sudoers?

I have tried:

```
user ALL= EXEC: PASSWD: /sbin/reboot ""
user ALL= EXEC: PASSWD: /sbin/reboot -f ""
```

But "sudo reboot -f" doesn not work.

Can I do something without add script reboot_f.sh with "/sbin/reboot -f"?

Comment: Try without the quotation marks for -f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the line:

```
user ALL= EXEC: PASSWD: /sbin/reboot ""
```

The quotes tells `sudo` that you only allow the user to use the `/sbin/reboot` command without argument. Otherwise, it would assume that you allow the user to use this command with any arguments.

The next line should be corrected as:

```
user ALL= EXEC: PASSWD: /sbin/reboot -f
```

As an argument is specifically provided, `sudo` restricts the user into using the command only with arguments matching the given pattern (here the literal option `-f`).

In your initial form you were requiring the user to use (the literal option `-f` followed by an empty value):

```
user@host$ sudo /sbin/reboot -f ""
```

Comment: Why can't I find this in the man page to visudo?